# Build a customizable trading engine in python

Tags: algorithmic-trading, python

I am planning building fully customizable backtesting trading engine in python from scratch as a open source project, 
the main features i am considering is,

- It should be fully customizable from top to bottom
- Customization is very easy and anyone can customize with a basic knowledge in python
- It have a in built template engine for reports which is also customizable
- Anyone can customize it as per their trading style

So what are the basic things which i have to consider for building a trading engine? 
Which are the python modules which is useful for this project
So anyone know any material regarding this sharing a link will be very helpful....

Comment: Why not use [zipline](https://github.com/quantopian/zipline), instead of re-inventing it?

Comment: Way too broad question. You emphasize customization requirements and that basically requires an incredible code stack that will be beyond any simple project. Just want you to be aware of the fact that you will most likely spend a year if you build from scratch. And I highly recommend not to attempt this project in Python but an OOP language that is much more performant, with a more stable and mature code base and that is actually suited to handle modules like broker API connectivity, OMS, PMS, parallel event based processing, and the like. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: I disagree on your latter statement: Python is more mature than say, Haskell (Tsuru, StanChart), Erlang (GSET) or OCaml (Jane St), so certainly, maturity isn't an issue.

Comment: I don't see why parallelization is an issue either. The GIL in Python leans towards a multi-process rather than a multithreading paradigm for parallelization, but there's no reason to prefer the latter over the former.

Comment: I also don't see why you can't do event-based processing in Python. You can write a TCP/IP stack in vanilla CPython if you wanted to, surely that's fast/robust enough considering some traders are using subpar trading platforms that don't even support basic order types such as HNS?

Comment: In the case of data analysis and pattern recognition python is the perfect suit, and python code always looks simple and sweet even your application is using even high complex machine learning algorithms. And i think if someone else use this they can think more about investment strategy other than coding and all other programming stuff. So i can't think other than python.

Comment: Two years too late - however, my twopence: Your question is far too broad, and I suspect from the "requirements" stated, that you are not a programmer yourself. Your best bet would be to break down your problem into smaller technical problems, and then ask in here on how to solve those problems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, you'll probably be directed to consider [Zipline](https://github.com/quantopian/zipline). It's worth a look but I don't think that it's a good starting point, since:

1. Quantopian's developers don't have a financial background and it shows through in the Zipline source code.
2. Zipline is dreadfully slow if you compare it to any commercial platform with backtesting functionality in a compiled application, even the low-end retail trading platforms (e.g. NinjaTrader, Sierra, TradeStation).
3. Zipline isn't very convenient for trading multiple products. I think the cheapest product that has that level of functionality is Deltix.

A modern processor should be able to backtest a moving average crossover strategy across an entire day of the OPRA feed (all products) without scheduling it overnight. Any less functionality or slower and you have poor developers. (I remember Goldman had 12-14 servers dealing with realtime OPRA in 2007-2008 and 2 persons rewrote the entire thing from scratch to target 128-bit architecture over a weekend. No reason why years of development on Zipline doesn't match up to 2 developers on a weekend before Stack Exchange existed.)

Here are some of the major considerations that you have to make before building your backtesting engine:

1. How will you be storing/serializing your market data on disk and in memory?

   - One poor man's approach is to wrap it around a `pandas` dataframe, but this comes at the cost of abstraction and will slow down your backtesting engine. `pandas` is nice for data exploration, but not for a task that you will repeat many times.
   - How will you handle a data source whose size exceeds available memory?
   - How will you deal with unstructured market data?
2. How will you be storing your outputs?

   - An obvious, naive problem is that you don't want to restart a backtest that took you 1 night to run if the application crashed midway. Another naive example is that you should be able to access old results from 6 months ago without repeating the backtest loop.
3. What's your fill logic?
4. What should your API expose? (e.g. Market orders, limit orders, instrument/price/volume queries, changes to fill logic)

Comment: I think pandas and HDF5 will be the good combination, But speed is still my biggest problem now. I am ready to do anything for make this super speed, have any idea?

Comment: In my mind one, the the worst lack of Zipline is the lack of bracket orders (Stop loss + Limit "child" orders attached to a parent order).

Comment: +1 for "Quantopian's developers don't have a financial background and it shows through in the Zipline source code".

Answer (score 0):

There are some other opensource projects at github along with zipline which you can check for some additional inputs for your thoughts.
Pyalgotrade is one such project where one can do back testing on their trading strategies

http://gbeced.github.io/pyalgotrade/